# Angular Manipulate Collection

Tags: angular, signalr

I am new to angular. My background is .NET (c#, wpf).

What I want to achieve is having a Collection which is bound to an table (datagrid).

The collection (EventData[]) will be fill by an http get request (getEvents).

Which is working by now.

Next I use the SignalR library to get new EventData objects pushed by the server.

So, if a new EventData is received, that data should be added to the existing collection and should be reflected to the view.

In c# it would be a simple "add" like "myEvents.Add(receivedEvent)".

Here is my code:

```
dataSource: EventData[];

ngOnInit() {

  this._hubconnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
    .withUrl('https://localhost:44373/notify')
    .build();

  this._hubconnection
    .start()
    .then(() => console.log('Connection Started'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection'));

  this._hubconnection.on('BroadcastMessage', (data: EventData) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.dataSource.push(data);
    // this.dataSource.subscribe(v => v.push(data));
  });

}
```

datasource is the eventData collection.

Comment: Is this not working? your code seems correct. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: The table does not show the added entry. I use the Material table with property binding [datasource]=“datasource“

Comment: would it be possible for you to create a stackblitz replicating this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to update your `MatTableDataSource` as well along with the `EventData[];`. To showcase this, I've created a sample [**StackBlitz Project**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal) for you.

As you can see, there's a button at the top that says `Add Item`. Clicking that button adds a new item to the table.

Once after updating the list of users, I'm setting the table data source to a new list like this:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users);
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much! I am trying to find out how to deal with angular and it seems that I will have to learn a lot of new things. From c# perspective angular/typescript it's weird. I didn't expect that you will allways have to create a whole new collection to if you add an entry. Best regards and thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I helped.